# SagePay Form - Success/Failure Url failing when encoded to RFC1738

Tags: php, opayo, rfc1738

We're just upgrading to form v3.0 and whilst doing so, refactoring our code.

Whilst doing so, we noticed that when using `http_build_query` which takes an associative array and converts it into an RFC1738 valid URL, that SagePay fails with the following error:

```
The SuccessURL format is invalid
```

The form submitting to the SagePay endpoint has an enctype of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

However... If we manually build the string to encrypt by doing:

```
$tmp = '';
foreach ($crypt_store as $key => $value) {
    $tmp .= sprintf('&%s=%s', $key, $value);
}
```

It works...

Now as I understand RFC1738, if an url exists within an url, it should be encoded, i.e.

RFC1738:

```
&VendorTxCode=Test&SuccessUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%3Fa%3Da%26b%3Db&FailureUrl...
```

SagePay:

```
&VendorTxCode=Test&SuccessUrl=http://www.stackoverflow.com?a=a&b=b&FailureUrl...
```

Surely if SagePay are following RFC1738, encoding the URL should work? Or is it because the string is encrypted which means it doesn't really matter?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Because the Success / Failure URLs are encrypted within the Crypt field, there is no need to encode them.

Comment: Except when they contain `&` or other special characters? This especially blows up when the URL contains parameters that match those used in crypt field. (From my testing and your answer, I assume you split the string on known parameter names rather than a more standard split on `&`).

Comment: Correct - so if your SuccessURL string contains &VendorTxCode= it's going to get removed.

Comment: @RikBlacow That's kinda ridiculous... The request body follows the "urlencoded-like" format, but we cannot actually escape the values according to the industry-standard RFCs. I'm just working with some legacy code and was really surprised when the request got broken (error 5080) after applying proper escaping to the user-provided data. If I'm supposed to leave it just as is, isn't it a security hole?